# website - from asp.net to PHP with keeping virtual directories as it is on windows server

Tags: php, asp.net, virtual-directory

i have domain xyz.com which is currently asp.net website, this domain has virtual directory named "Control", i access this virtual directory through xyz.com/Control , which is also asp.net

Now i have created PHP version of xyz.com and i want to upload it to server.

i want virtual directories to function as it is.
control panel shows files for xyz.com falls under "/httpdocs" folder

so if through ftp i deleted all files under "/httpdocs" and upload my php files to it , will it work ? and my virtual directories will function as it is ?

or deleting files under "/httpdocs" will remove virtual directories too ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything that does public on Apache server mainly lives under Httpdocs
So your virtual directory will also live there 
you should be able to access the directory as before through xyz.com/Contro it should not change anything

Comment: so xyz.com/ will have php files and xyz.com/Control/ will have asp.net files, both will function normally with out any issues ?!

Comment: Do you want to run asp and php files on same server? If yes then use iis7 it supports asp.net and php both